# Fit ContentDialog RequestedTheme On Load Event Automatically on UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

How can I fit ContentDialog RequestedTheme on load event with code same as global theme setting (dark or light) automatically on UWP ? I used this trick however it is not effective:

```
private void ContentDialog_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
        {
           string device = Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily; // (Mobile, Team(Surface Hub), Desktop, IoT. Device types.
 if (device == "Windows.Mobile") // If it is a phone
            {


       RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Default; // Enable automatic theming in mobile.

            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: By default the content dialog will fit the global theme automatically, I can't reproduce your problem, where did you set the theme? And your `ContentDialog_Loading` event should be triggered when the page (which hold this content dialog) is loading. How did you create your ContentDialog?

Comment: Hi. I created my content dialog via XAML, not code. I set ContentDialog RequestedTheme to "Light" on XAML designer for running in desktop mode correctly. Yes, you are right. Loading event triggered while loading, however I want do this one : If device is a Windows Phone, set theme to phone default (Dark or Light) for ContentDialog. My problem is, ContentDialog theme is "Dark" at everytime if device is Windows Phone by default . Changing from "Settings" have not any effect.How can I solve this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are specifying theme values at run-time after [Applicaition.RequestedTheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is applied, for example like this:

```
contentDialog.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Default;
```

As you can see in [ElementTheme enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.elementtheme), when you set it to `Default`, it uses the `Application.RequestedTheme` value for the element.

So I think somewhere in your code, you have set the `Application.RequestedTheme` to `Dark` when you run your code on mobile.

To make the `ContentDialog`'s theme or app's theme changing according to settings by user, by default you can just remove the `RequestedTheme="Dark"` or `RequestedTheme="Light"` in your App.xaml file, and don't set any `Application.RequestedTheme` in the code behind. There is no need to apply the `ElementTheme` to `ContentDialog` unless you want to change its theme different from settings.